# Strange cflocation behavior: redirecting to page but not updating url

Tags: jquery-mobile, redirect, coldfusion, cflocation

I have a basic mobile login page in ColdFusion that allows the user to enter a username and password and log in. On successful login, the page redirects to the home page using a cflocation. However, while the page redirects successfully to the home page, it still displays the login page URL in the location bar. We have used cflocation many times throughout our web application and I have never come across this behavior before and can't figure out what could be causing it.

The gist of the page code:

```
<cfparam name="invalidLogin" default="false">
<cfif cgi.REQUEST_METHOD EQ "POST" AND isDefined("form.email") AND isDefined("form.password") and len(trim(form.email)) and len(trim(form.password))>
    <!--- call the login method --->
    <cfinvoke component="login" method="userlogin" returnvariable="userData">
        <cfinvokeargument name="userName" value="#form.email#">
        <cfinvokeargument name="password" value="#form.password#">
    </cfinvoke>

    <cfif userData.isLoggedIn>
        <cflocation url="index.cfm" addtoken="no">
    </cfif>
    <cfset invalidLogin = true />
</cfif>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Log In</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" class="bg-color">
            <div class="container">
                <div data-role="content">
                    <div class="article">
                        <div class="logoDiv">
                            <img src="img/companyLogo.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <form action="" method="post" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" class="margin-top" data-transition="slide">
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Username">
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <cfif invalidLogin><div>Invalid Login</div></cfif>
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Log In" data-theme="b" />   
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this happen on all devices and mobile browsers?

Comment: @Antony - so far I'm just testing on my computer's web browser, I haven't yet tested on mobile devices

Comment: maybe it has to do with jQM Ajax navigation. Try adding `data-ajax=false` to `form`.

Comment: have you tried using firebug to see whats going on in the DOM?

Comment: @Omar - that fixes it, thanks! If you post it as an answer (a link to the docs about the attribute would be helpful too) I'll accept

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :)

Comment: @Omar - post it as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent jQuery Mobile from handling *forms* with *redirect* via Ajax, you need to turn Ajax Navigation off and handle the request through HTTP.

To do so, add `data-ajax="false"` attribute to `form` tag. This will stop Ajax Navigation on the *form* only.

**Note** that you will lose transition when moving for current form page to new page as Ajax is turned off, so `data-transition="slide"` will have no effect.

```
<form action="" data-ajax="false" method="post" name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin">
```